# On demand image slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider, ondemand

Is there any solution to display more than 10000 images with an image slider? the images paths  are returned from a db search request as json data.

Comment: Try some sliders and see which one works better? Or did you write a script and it's not working properly?

Comment: i tried over 10 sliders but the problem is that they  load all the images in the page before starting the slider which lead to crash problems ...

Comment: Your server should return only x number of images at a time and create a pagination. When changing page you request the next number of images and reload the slider. I'm not aware of any slider that will do this unless it's custom made and I'm afraid this is the wrong place to ask for plugins